# If $y\in\mathbb R^+$ then $\exists~m\in\mathbb N$ such that $0<\dfrac{1}{2^m}<y$

Tags: real-analysis

> Using **Archimedean Property** how to show the following:
>
> If $y\in\mathbb R^+$ then $\exists~m\in\mathbb N$ such that $0<\dfrac{1}{2^m}<y.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Start by showing that:

> $$\forall n\in \mathbb{N}[n<2^n]$$

Answer (score 0):

First use the Archimedean Property to show that there is a positive integer $m$ that is $\gt \frac{1}{y}$. Then prove, perhaps by induction, that $2^m \gt m$.